# Import Extension file in Swift

Tags: ios, uiview, swift

I create an extension for UIView in Swift. Anyone knows how to import that file to my UIViewController?

I want to import the extension file in the controller file, in that way I can reuse the extension file. For example an structure like this:

UIViewExtension.swift

```
import UIKit

extension UIView {
    var myVar : Float {
        get {
            return myVar
        }
        set (newMyVar) {
            myVar = newMyVar
        }
    }
}
```

ViewController.swift

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        var squareView: UIView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 200))

        squareView.myVar = 50

        self.view.addSubview(squareView)
        println("Offset: \(squareView.myVar)")
    }
}
```

This is the error given by the compiler:

`Command /Applications/Xcode6-Beta.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift failed with exit code 254`

Comment: This looks like a bug in the compiler. It won't work for me either, unless I bring the extension into "ViewController.swift", above the class definition.

Comment: That is right, I've checked the extension in the same file as `ViewController.swift` before posting, so it works fine. Also autosuggestion for`import` doesn't work, even for UIKit

Comment: Could you try to add a class declaration to the file with the extension? E.g. `class TestClass {}`. Maybe it will help the compiler to find the extension...

Answer (score 8):

There several things going on here.

1. There is no need to import extensions as you have to for Objective-C, as everything in the same module is automatically available to you in Swift. This means that your extension is actually successfully visible to the compiler in your view controller.
2. You can only add computed properties to an extension. This means that you do not actually have a myVar to assign to or read from. So when you access `myVar` you are actually recursing infinitely. That is actually what the warning is alluding to (albeit in vague way):

   ```
   warning: attempting to access 'myVar' within its own getter
     return myVar
            ^
   ```
3. As far as I know, there is no way to add non-computed properties to a type using an extension. This is also true of Objective-C where the only way to actually store a property added to a class using a class extension is to use Objective-C object association via `objc_getAssociatedObject` and `objc_setAssociatedObject` from `objc/runtime.h`.
4. Finally there is definitely a bug in the compiler if your extension's computed property has a setter. The minimum working example to reproduce the bug, which does not include recursion (by eliminating the access to myVar) and just ignore the value is:

   ```
   import UIKit

   extension UIView {
     var myVar : Float {
     get {
       return 0
     }
     set {
     }
     }
   }
   ```

Comment: My question then it is about the 3 and 4 points. How to add new properties as objC to an extension without getter? But even that the error still appears when the extension is called from the ViewController

Comment: The only way I know of to achieve what you are attempting to do is with Objective-C, cf. http://nshipster.com/associated-objects/

Comment: Re 4. you should definitely report the bug to Apple at https://bugreport.apple.com/

Comment: I've done it with objC, that's why I am trying to do with Swift ;)

Comment: Doesn't matter if it has a setter or not, or if it's a correct computed-only-var. I get the same error `1.While emitting IR SIL function @_TFC16<appname>13EPAppDelegate11applicationfS0_FTCSo13UIApplication29didFinishLaunchingWithOptionsGSqCSo12NSDictionary__Sb for 'application' at filename.swift:21:5
<unknown>:0: error: unable to execute command: Segmentation fault: 11
<unknown>:0: error: swift frontend command failed due to signal (use -v to see invocation)
Command /Applications/Xcode6-Beta.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift failed with exit code 254`

Comment: I'm getting very similar compiler errors (with different class and method names) all over my project that I'm migrating from Objective-C to Swift. Has anyone reported this? And how fast can I expect Apple to fix this? It's brought my development to a halt :/

Comment: Using **static** in front of property declaration seems to do the trick

Answer (score 2):

I encountered this issue as well. It appears that it is a compiler bug. The compiler seems to crash if you have computed properties in a standalone extension file. The workaround I have found is to create the extension in non-standalone file. So in this case you could move your extension into your ViewController.swift file. Like so:

```
import UIKit

extension UIView {
    var myVar : Float {
        get {
            return myVar
        }
        set (newMyVar) {
            myVar = newMyVar
        }
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        var squareView: UIView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 200))

        squareView.myVar = 50

        self.view.addSubview(squareView)
        println("Offset: \(squareView.myVar)")
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice finding! Did you report the bug with Apple (https://bugreport.apple.com) or is it a known issue?

Comment: Please report this to Apple!

Comment: Using **static** in front of the property declaration seems to do the trick. I added a code example as an answer!

Answer (score 0):

After selecting the file in Xcode in the Project navigator on the left, make sure you check the app and test in the Target Membership section in the Inspector view on the right.

If it is not checked then it won't be included in the project and hence you will get the compile error.

[image]

Comment: Worked for me, allowed me to use the extension written in source code from inside a unit test.

Answer (score -1):

Using **static** in front of the property declaration seems to do the trick.

```
extension UIView {
    static var myVar : Float {
        get {
            return myVar
        }
        set (newMyVar) {
            myVar = newMyVar
        }
    }
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: This creates a class variable which is shared by all instances rather than an instance variable. This may well work if you know you will never have more than one instance but you fail to indicate this major pitfall in your answer.